# Different display on laptop's screen and projector screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, presentations

I saw a lecturer using PowerPoint to present his lecture, however, I notice that although the projector only show the PowerPoint's slides, his laptop screen show different things. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe 'extending' your desktop should do the trick, as opposed to cloning. This is standard on nearly every system that supports more than one monitor.

Comment: Can you explain how to extend the desktop? I tried Google, but all solutions requires second monitor, but now I'm at home, and I don't have it.

Comment: Well, in his case, the projector acts as a second monitor. I suppose you may be able to simulate this with a second computer and zonescreen, but it is somewhat illogical to try to emulate a two monitor setup with one monitor

Comment: Some more possible solutions - [Microsoft India, Split screen desktop](http://www.engadget.com/2007/05/06/microsoft-researching-split-screen-desktop-software/) (unreleased), [Virtual Dimension](http://virt-dimension.sourceforge.net/) (open source & developed) and [ATI Hydravision](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/hydravision.aspx) (which i don't think they develop anymore)

Comment: The first seems the closest to what he needs, short of actually borrowing a monitor. He dosen't need virtual desktops, and hydravision is multiscreen management. He can quite easily do what he is talking about on *any* dual screen system

Comment: Assuming your using windows, the shortcut Win+P brings up the projector options, here you can toggle to "Extend" and you now have an extra desktop on the second display

Answer (score 1):

After extending your desktop as @Journeyman Geek suggests, you need to enable dual monitor support in Powerpoint. If you are using Powerpoint 2007, you can do this by selecting the `Slide Show` tab on the ribbon, and select the monitor that you want to show the presentation on under `Monitors`.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2013, while the presentation is running, you can right-click the screen and the appropriate option for divided views

Answer (score 0):

if your are using PowerPoint 2013, Yes you can do that. 
Play your slide in Presentation Mode. then press down Key of (Windows + D). 
Now you will see your Desktop screen, and your Projector slide still on Going without disturbing.